# TensorFlow Estimator restoring all variables properly, but loss spikes up afterwards

Tags: tensorflow

I am using TensorFlow 1.2.1 on Windows 10, and using the Estimator API.  Everything runs without any errors, but whenever I have to restore the parameters from a checkpoint, some aspect of it doesn't work. I've checked that the values of every variable in classifier.get_variable_names() does not change after an evaluation, however the Loss spikes back up to near where it started, this is followed by a continued learning, each time learning faster than the last.

This happens within one TensorFlow run, when a validation or evaluation run happens, or when I rerun the python file to continue training.

The following graphs are one example of this problem, they are restoring the variables every 2500 steps:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/gwfgL.jpg

https://i.stack.imgur.com/HRHMz.jpg

The following code is a significiantly reduced version of my code, which still replicates the error:

```
import tensorflow as tf
from tensorflow.contrib import learn
from tensorflow.contrib.learn.python.learn.estimators import model_fn as model_fn_lib

tf.logging.set_verbosity(tf.logging.INFO)

sess = tf.InteractiveSession()

def cnn_model_fn(features, labels, mode):

    dense_layer1 = tf.layers.dense(inputs=features, units=512, activation=tf.nn.relu, name="FC_1")
    dense_layer2 = tf.layers.dense(inputs=dense_layer1, units=1024, activation=tf.nn.relu, name="FC_2")
    dense_layer3 = tf.layers.dense(inputs=dense_layer2, units=2048, activation=tf.nn.relu, name="FC_3")
    dense_layer4 = tf.layers.dense(inputs=dense_layer3, units=512, activation=tf.nn.relu, name="FC_4")
    logits = tf.layers.dense(inputs=dense_layer4, units=2, name="logit_layer")

    loss = None
    train_op = None

    if mode != learn.ModeKeys.INFER:
        loss = tf.losses.softmax_cross_entropy(
            onehot_labels=labels, logits=logits)

    if mode == learn.ModeKeys.TRAIN:
        train_op = tf.contrib.layers.optimize_loss(
            loss=loss,
            global_step=tf.contrib.framework.get_global_step(),
            learning_rate=.001,
            optimizer="SGD")

    predictions = {
        "classes": tf.argmax(input=logits, axis=1),
        "probabilities": tf.nn.softmax(
        logits, name="softmax_tensor")}


    return model_fn_lib.ModelFnOps(
        mode=mode, 
        predictions=predictions,
        loss=loss,
        train_op=train_op)



def main(unused_param):
    def data_pipeline(filenames, batch_size, num_epochs=None, min_after_dequeue=10000):
        with tf.name_scope("data_pipeline"):
            filename_queue = tf.train.string_input_producer(filenames, num_epochs=num_epochs)

            reader = tf.TextLineReader()
            key, value = reader.read(filename_queue)

            row = tf.decode_csv(value, record_defaults=[[0.0] for _ in range(66)])

            example_op, label_op  = tf.stack(row[:len(row)-2]), tf.stack(row[len(row)-2:]) 

            capacity = min_after_dequeue + 3 * batch_size 

            example_batch, label_batch = tf.train.shuffle_batch(
                [example_op, label_op],
                batch_size=batch_size,
                capacity=capacity,
                min_after_dequeue=min_after_dequeue)

            return example_batch, label_batch


    def input_data_fn(data_getter_ops):
        batch, labels = sess.run(data_getter_ops)
        return tf.constant(batch, dtype=tf.float32), tf.constant(labels, dtype=tf.float32)

    NUM_EPOCHS =  6     
    BATCHES_IN_TRAINING_EPOCH = 8000


    training_data_pipe_ops = data_pipeline(
        filenames=["train_data.csv"],
        batch_size=500, 
        min_after_dequeue=10000)

    coord = tf.train.Coordinator()
    threads = tf.train.start_queue_runners(coord=coord)

    classifier = tf.contrib.learn.Estimator(
        model_fn=cnn_model_fn,
        model_dir="/tmp/bug_finder")

    for j in range(NUM_EPOCHS):
        classifier.fit(
            input_fn=lambda: input_data_fn(training_data_pipe_ops),
            steps = BATCHES_IN_TRAINING_EPOCH)

        print("Epoch", str(j+1), "training completed.")

    coord.request_stop()
    coord.join(threads)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    tf.app.run()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured out the issue, I was creating data pipelines with the interactive session I created, and then having my input function evaluate the examples (like a feed-dictionary).  The reason this is an issue is that the Estimator class creates it's own session (a MonitoredTraininSession), and since the graph operations weren't being created from within a call from the Estimator class (and thus with it's session), they were not being saved.  Using an input function to create the graph operations, and return the final graph operation (the batching) has resulted in everything working smoothly.

Comment: Can you show how you solved this? I'm having a similar issue with a custom data set.

Comment: I have since converted the input pipeline to use the tf.data module, and it is MUCH simpler to use.  I would check that every op being created is created from within an internal call by the Estimator, so make sure you don't call the function to create the input pipeline, let the Estimator call it.

Comment: Thanks for the tip on when to instantiate the pipeline. Are you using a "normal" data format that plays nice with the data set class or using a custom reader op?  I would be interested for seeing your implementation to solve a similar issue I am having.

Comment: My data is a chess board, which I'm now taking in as 64 uint8s  from a tfrecords file (for training).  For inference I'm taking some uint64 and a lookup table to unpack the bits of the numbers as boolean arrays.  

By the end of the day I'll be doing a big commit which involves new pipelines and removes old, so depending on when you look you may need to go into previous iterations. But here is my [github repo](https://github.com/SamRagusa/Batch-First)